# MD5 or other certification for R Package Download

Tags: r, security, package, md5

Many R Packages (cran.r-project.org) contain the MD5 strings for R package components, but only as part of the download.  The underlying purpose is to foster a high degree of trust in the validity of downloaded binaries.  I have searched for, and can't find in any R documentation, a separate location where the MD5 strings can be found (cf. Apache).  The idea is to have the strings for verification but not part of the same zip file.  Has anyone found such a location?  Hopefully an R Foundation member or Member at Large can directly speak to plans for this? Forgive my ignorance if I have missed something obvious.  Thanks!

Comment: MD5 is broken enough that it's pretty pointless for anything but a simple checksum. In reality you should be looking at GPG signed packages for security and integrity verification.

Comment: Good point.  Please revise my question to include the resulting inquiry regarding any known plans or effort under way to provide this for R packages?  Thanks!

Comment: R Project != CRAN.  Your question is specific to CRAN, and only the CRAN maintainers could answer it (if they chose to do so).  With that, I suggest posting on r-devel rather than here.